# How do I fill a table with values from my function?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

With the following function,

```
 PoissonBinomialSuccess[plist_, t_] := Flatten[With[{n = Length@plist, c = Exp[(2 I \[Pi])/(Length@plist + 1)]}, success = Probability[{k >= t}, k \[Distributed] (ProbabilityDistribution[Re[1/(n + 1) Sum[c^(-l k) Product[1 + (c^l - 1) plist[[m]], {m, 1, n}], {l,0, n}]], {k, 0, n, 1} ])]]] /; AllTrue[plist, 0 <= # <= 1 &]
```

I wish to populate a table with outputs by that function. For example, defining $plist$ and $t$ as shown below, I would like to create a table. The purpose is to create a 3D plot.

**Edit / Clarification:** I am only interested in the information that I have indicated by the square (so, the headings are unimportant). Also, the plists are vectors of homogeneous probabilities, that increment by some fixed magnitude. For example {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},  {0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1}, {0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2}, ... {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}.

For example, using @Bob Hanlon's approach below, the following is what I image. But I am very surprised that it appears problematic to display a 3D plot of the content:

```
TableForm[ table = Outer[PoissonBinomialSuccess[#1, #2][[1]] &, plist, tlist, 1]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at documentation for [`Outer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html)

```
PoissonBinomialSuccess[plist_, t_] :=
 Flatten[
   With[{
     n = Length@plist,
     c = Exp[(2 I π)/(Length@plist + 1)]},
    success = Probability[{k >= t},
      k \[Distributed] (ProbabilityDistribution[Re[1/(n + 1)* 
           Sum[
            c^(-l k)* 
             Product[
              1 + (c^l - 1) plist[[m]],
              {m, 1, n}],
            {l, 0, n}]],
         {k, 0, n, 1}])]]] /;
  AllTrue[plist, 0 <= # <= 1 &]
```

**EDIT:**

```
plist = ConstantArray[#, 5] & /@ Range[0, 1, .1];

tlist = Range[5];

TableForm[
 table = Outer[
   PoissonBinomialSuccess[#1, #2][[1]] &,
   plist, tlist, 1],
 TableHeadings -> {
   StringForm["plist=``", #] & /@ plist,
   StringForm["t=``", #] & /@ tlist},
 TableAlignments -> {".", Center}]
```

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

```
ListPlot3D[Table[
   {p, t, PoissonBinomialSuccess[ConstantArray[p, 5], t][[1]]},
   {p, 0, 1, .05}, {t, Range[5]}] // Flatten[#, 1] &,
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@{"p", "t", "Success"})]
```

[image]

Comment: my aim is to create plist as lists of homogeneous probabilities that increments from 0 to 1. It doesn't look as if Tuples can help me do that.

Comment: @user120911 - recommend that you edit your question to clarify how `plist` is defined.

Comment: I should have been more clear. My apologies. This answer is almost as I imaged. I imagined only the core part (without the headings), but again, I probably was not very clear about thaty either. I will edit my question, as you suggest.

Comment: @user120911 - the "core" part is defined in the code as `table`. You can display it by `table//Grid` or `table//MatrixForm`

Comment: The following is exactly what I imaged. But I am very surprised that it is problematic to display a 3D plot of the content:

TableForm[
 table = Outer[PoissonBinomialSuccess[#1, #2][[1]] &, plist, tlist, 
   1]]

Comment: @user120911 are you trying to 3D plot the TableForm wrapper and all? That might be your issue.